# runtime error -2147024809 (80070057) pivottable field name is not valid

Tags: excel, vba

Receive above error when running creating pivot. Not sure why, this works perfectly fine in another workbook:

Says I need to Debug this section

```
Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
  Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache _
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)
```

Comment: Without seeing the current pivottable or the new data source, I'm not sure there's much we can offer.  Have you checked out previous posts here on this topic?   https://www.google.com/search?q=pivottable+field+name+is+not+valid+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes I have spent countless hours researching. This is literally just a copy and paste of a workbook to a new workbook with new data headers for the pivot table.

Comment: Adding more of your code might be useful here.

Comment: It wouldn't let me in the original post, it kept giving me an error that I had too much code in the post without enough background/question info. Here's a new error I'm getting: 

Compile error: Sub or Function not defined
in reference to this part of my code: 

    
```
Sub CreateSummary()
    Dim Err As Boolean: Err = False

    If CopyPivot() Then Exit Sub
    If FormatPivotCells() Then Exit Sub
    Call AdjustPivotDataRange

    End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like one or more of the methods `CopyPivot`, `FormatPivotCells`, or `AdjustPivotDataRange` is missing.  Which exact line gives you the error?

Comment: AdjustPivotDataRange

Comment: Your code can't see that method - it either doesn't exist or it's defined somewhere where it's not visible to your code.

Comment: Would you be willing to look at my sheet with me or look it over? I think I fixed that error, I believe part of the code was missing. I'm now getting the original error and I've combed over the sheet and I can't figure out what I'm missing. My coworker set this sheet up, they no longer work here, and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: If you're able to share the workbook via email I can take a look.  Let me know and I'll drop my mail here.

Comment: Sorry, I had to put this to the side and found a work around, but I'd love to be able to fix this worksheet. I can share it via email if you provide yours. :-) Thanks!!

Comment: Left my email here for a day but no response - leave yours if you still need help and I'll mail you...